# Export table content to text format in pdf using iTextSharp.text

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to Export database table content in my pdf through the code on clicking on a link button I am calling this following function on a link button

```
        public void EXportCaseAsText(int caseid)
        {

        DateTime pubdate = new DateTime();
       // System.IO.MemoryStream msReport = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        int pageno = 1, questionno = 1;
        int count = BlFactory.CipCaseWorkflowItemBl.LoadWorkflowForCase(caseid).Count;
        Font HeaderFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 14, Font.BOLD, iTextSharp.text.Color.RED);
        Font OptionsFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, Font.BOLD, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
        Font TrueFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, Font.UNDERLINE, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLUE);
        Font dataFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, Font.NORMAL, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
        Font datefont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 14, Font.BOLD, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLUE);
        if (count > 0)
        {

            try
            {
                Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
                //PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("D:\\RCMS\\Acr3S.Cmf.Web\\bin\\Debug\\my.pdf", FileMode.Create));

                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);

                document.Open();

                DateTime pub = getCasePublishedDate(caseid);
                if (pub.ToShortDateString().Equals("1/1/0001"))
                {
                    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(new Paragraph("Not yet published",datefont));
                    paragraph.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                    document.Add(paragraph);
                }
                else
                {
                    string date = DateFormatter.GetFormattedDate(pub);
                    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(new Paragraph(date, datefont));
                    paragraph.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                    document.Add(paragraph);

                }

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    CipCaseWorkflowItem item = (new NHibernate.DebugHelpers.CollectionProxy<Acr3S.Core.Domain.CipCaseWorkflowItem>
                                            (BlFactory.CipCaseWorkflowItemBl.LoadWorkflowForCase(caseid))).Items[i];

                    switch (item.Type)
                    {
                        case CaseContentItemType.BaseCaseTextElement:
                            {
                                CipTextElementScriptItem textItem = (CipTextElementScriptItem)BlFactory.CipCaseWorkflowItemBl.LoadWorkflowForCase(caseid, item.Id);

                                if (textItem != null && textItem.Id!=null && textItem.ContentElement !=null)
                                {
                                    switch (textItem.ElementType.ToString())
                                    {
                                        case "Diagnosis":
                                            {
                                                Paragraph par = new Paragraph("Diagnosis", HeaderFont);
                                                //Chunk chunk = new Chunk(textItem.ContentElement.PlainText.Trim(), dataFont);
                                                //par.Add("\n");
                                                //par.Add(chunk);
                                                document.Add(par);
                                                StyleSheet styles = new StyleSheet();
                                                ArrayList objects = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(textItem.ContentElement.Text), styles);
                                                for (int k = 0; k < objects.Count; ++k)
                                                {
                                                    document.Add((IElement)objects[k]);
                                                }
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        case "History":
                                            {
                                                Paragraph par = new Paragraph("History", HeaderFont);
                                                //Chunk chunk = new Chunk(textItem.ContentElement.PlainText.Trim(), dataFont);
                                                //par.Add("\n");
                                                //par.Add(chunk);
                                                document.Add(par);
                                                StyleSheet styles = new StyleSheet();
                                                ArrayList objects = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(textItem.ContentElement.Text), styles);
                                                for (int k = 0; k < objects.Count; ++k)
                                                {
                                                    document.Add((IElement)objects[k]);
                                                }
                                                break;
                                            }



                                        case "Discussion":
                                            {
                                                Paragraph par = new Paragraph("Discussion", HeaderFont);
                                                //par.Add("\n");
                                                //Chunk chunk = new Chunk(textItem.ContentElement.PlainText.Trim(), dataFont);
                                                //par.Add(chunk);
                                                document.Add(par);
                                                StyleSheet styles = new StyleSheet();
                                                ArrayList objects = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(textItem.ContentElement.Text), styles);
                                                for (int k = 0; k < objects.Count; ++k)
                                                {
                                                    document.Add((IElement)objects[k]);
                                                }
                                                break;
                                            }


                                        case "CasePoints":
                                            {
                                                Paragraph par = new Paragraph("Case Points", HeaderFont);
                                                //Chunk chunk = new Chunk(textItem.ContentElement.PlainText.Trim(), dataFont);
                                                //par.Add("\n");
                                                //par.Add(chunk);
                                                document.Add(par);
                                                StyleSheet styles = new StyleSheet();
                                                ArrayList objects = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(textItem.ContentElement.Text), styles);
                                                for (int k = 0; k < objects.Count; ++k)
                                                {
                                                    document.Add((IElement)objects[k]);
                                                }
                                                break;
                                            }



                                    }
                                }

                                break;
                            }

                    }
                }
                document.Close();
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + getCaseName(caseid) + ".pdf");
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.End();

            }

            catch (DocumentException de)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(de.Message);
            }


        }

    }
```

The problem is somethime Discussion data is not showing in pdf something History data is not showing in pdf sometime case point data is not showing in pdf while all data is present in table

I am not getting why it is happening

Comment: I think there is an error near for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
document.Add(par);
StyleSheet styles = new StyleSheet();
ArrayList objects = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(textItem.ContentElement.Text), styles);
for (int k = 0; k < objects.Count; ++k)
{
  document.Add((IElement)objects[k]);
}
```

By

// New Code implemented:

```
document.Add(par);
StyleSheet styles = new StyleSheet();
string tempText = textItem.ContentElement.Text;
tempText = tempText.Replace("\"", "&#34;");
ArrayList objects = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(tempText), styles);
for (int k = 0; k < objects.Count; ++k)
{
    document.Add((IElement)objects[k]);
}
```

this will work fine...