# asp.NET - Save HTML String to PDF

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, pdf

```
Dim HTMLstr as String
```

in this variable I am writing pure **HTML code** then displaying it in a **label** in **asp.net**

```
   HTMLstr  = "<table width=""auto;"">  "
   HTMLstr  &= "<tr style=""color:white ; background: #336699; font-style:bold;"">"
   HTMLstr  &= "<th width=""257px;"" height=""40"" >Service Name</th>"
   HTMLstr  &= "<th width=""100px;"" height=""40"">Hits </th>"
   HTMLstr  &= "<th width=""100px;"" height=""40"">Revenue</th>"
   HTMLstr  &= "<th width=""100px;"" height=""40"">Service Cost</th>"
   HTMLstr  &= "</tr></table>"

   Label_Html.Text = HTMLStr
```

I want to export the **whole HTML String to PDF**

What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Simplest way? just print it in a chrome and save as pdf

Comment: @dholakiyaankit Something that would work on all browsers?

Comment: User Itextsharp Open source library

Comment: Try this http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/HTML-to-PDF-conversion-using-iTextsharp-1088.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link shows someone else trying to do something similar.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1805488.aspx

The question asked by that OP was answered with these three links so you may want to review them too.

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-ASPNet-Web-Page-with-images-to-PDF-using-ITextsharp.aspx

[Export table content to text format in pdf using iTextSharp.text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262028/export-table-content-to-text-format-in-pdf-using-itextsharp-text)

http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.in/2008/07/how-to-export-content-of-gridview-to.html